# How to get a distinct sub document list by excluding one named field?

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking for a pre 3.4 solution (i.e. no replaceRoot and project by exclusion option) for how to get a distinct list of sub document values, by excluding one named field.

I have something like:-

```
{
"field1":"sadasdasdasdas",
"field2":"whatever bla dasdasda",
"source_display_tags" : {
        "name" : "Hot Toast Cafe",
        "updateId" : NumberLong(12345),
        "address" : "2 Burnt Street",
        "postal_code" : "HT1 8RT",
        "town" : "Breadville"
    }
}
```

And I wish to get **a distinct list of source_display_tags by excluding the updateId field**, i.e.

```
{
    "source_display_tags" : {
        "name" : "Hot Toast Cafe",
        "address" : "2 Burnt Street",
        "postal_code" : "HT1 8RT",
        "town" : "Breadville"}
},
{
    "source_display_tags" : {
        "name" : "Banana Grove Restaurant",
         etc...
```

in some way which does not involve naming any of the other fields. i.e. I don't want to do this:-

```
db.getCollection('updates').aggregate([
{$unwind:"$source_display_tags"},
{"$project": {_id:0, name: "$source_display_tags.name", address: "$source_display_tags.address", town: "$source_display_tags.town", postal_code: "$source_display_tags.postal_code"}},
{ $group: { _id: { name: "$name", address: "$address", town: "$town", postal_code:"$postal_code"}}}
])
```

Is there any way to produce this output **by only naming the "updateId" field**?

Comment: Please add a sample of your expected output, to get a clear understanding of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hopefully the above edit helps. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Add another [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) to your existing query and that will do the magic for us, In the $project pipeline have a tag named `source_display_tags` and pass the content of `_id` (from the previous pipeline result) to this tag and suppress the `_id`,

here is the query

```
db.getCollection('updates').aggregate([ 
     {$unwind:"$source_display_tags"}, 
     {"$project": { _id:0,
               name: "$source_display_tags.name", 
               address: "$source_display_tags.address", 
               town: "$source_display_tags.town", 
               postal_code: "$source_display_tags.postal_code"
     }}, 
     { "$group": {
                _id: {
                        name: "$name",
                        address: "$address",
                        town: "$town", 
                        postal_code:"$postal_code"
                }}
      }, 
      {"$project":{source_display_tags: "$_id", "_id":0}} 
])
```

If there is no need of grouping we can simply use the below find query

```
db.so.find( {},
            {
             "source_display_tags.name":1,
              "source_display_tags.address":1, 
              "source_display.tags.postal_code":1, 
              "source_display_tags.town":1, 
              _id:0
            }
);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this required naming all the fields to be **included** - The question was is there a way to get to the result by only naming the field to be **excluded**, which in the case of this example is updateId. Thanks.